# Autocomplete doesn't work - DataTables + Yadcf

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, jquery-ui-autocomplete, yadcf

I created a table with DataTables and Yadcf plugins. It uses server side processing. I added an autocomplete filter to the second column and add yadcf_data_1 field in server response, but when typing nothing happens. Also, there aren't any errors in javascript console.

You can see my table [here](http://sunstorm.tk/publ/webm_stats/).

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        table = $('#table').DataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": {
                "url": "server_processing.php",
                "type": "POST"
            },
            "language": {
                "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.11/i18n/Russian.json"
            },
            "searching": false,
            dom: 'lfrtip<"#table_buttons"B>',
            buttons: [
                {
                    text: 'Экспорт в CSV',
                    action: function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
                        if(last_data) {
                            last_data['export'] = 1;
                            downloadFile("server_processing.php?" + $.param(last_data));
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "columnDefs": [
                {className: "center", "targets": [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]}
            ]
        });

        yadcf.init(table, [
            {
                column_number: 0,
                filter_default_label: '--- Все ---'
            },
            {
                column_number: 1,
                filter_default_label: 'Введите',
                filter_type: "auto_complete",
            },
            {
                column_number: 2,
                filter_type: "range_number",
                filter_delay: 500,
                filter_default_label: ['от', 'до']
            },
            {
                column_number: 3,
                filter_type: "range_number",
                filter_delay: 500,
                filter_default_label: ['от', 'до']
            },
            {
                column_number: 4,
                filter_type: "range_number",
                filter_delay: 500,
                filter_default_label: ['от', 'до']
            },
            {
                column_number: 5,
                filter_type: "range_number",
                filter_delay: 500,
                filter_default_label: ['от', 'до']
            },
            {
                column_number: 6,
                filter_type: "range_number",
                filter_delay: 500,
                filter_default_label: ['от', 'до']
            },
            {
                column_number: 7,
                filter_type: "range_number",
                filter_delay: 500,
                filter_default_label: ['от', 'до']
            },
            {
                column_number: 8,
                filter_type: "range_number",
                filter_delay: 500,
                filter_default_label: ['от', 'до']
            },


        ]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `searching": false,` from your init code because it disables searching functionality from your table